# Paypal Sandbox issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to setup a sandbox account with paypal , I have a developer account already .

But as soon as I click on the link which says"Click here" to go to www.sandbox.paypal.com to link up my existing accounts it throws out the below error . Anyone facing the same issue , need help.
We're sorry.

```
Relying party validation error: client_id or redirect_url provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request and try again.
```

Comment: Paypal sandboxing is quite confusing ...

Comment: Does anyone know any tutorials or walkthrough for the paypal sandbox, Its one of the most complicated stuff they have come up with..

Comment: I am experiencing issues with the sandbox and Chrome also, it seems to be not working at all right now. Opening Sandbox page just redirects to main PayPal site. I tried using other browser and this fixed my problem. Open the link using incognito tab or other browsers like Firefox.

Comment: Same here , I even encountered one error -The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.While trying to test one subscriber button,I integrated for a website.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing issues with the sandbox also, it seems to be not working at all right now. Opening [Sandbox page](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) just redirects to main PayPal site. According to [Sandbox overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_overview/) the url was not changed, so hopefully it will be working in a moment.

Comment: Exactly , its been like this since morning... tried 1000 times .But thank God I am not the only one having this issue , coz I was worried about me not been able to test one of my implementations.